# Tomcat installation, where to set environmantal variables?

Tags: tomcat, installation, environment-variables

I am working my way through the RUNNING.txt file for installing Tomcat.

It says:

```
(3.1) Set CATALINA_HOME (required) and CATALINA_BASE (optional)

The CATALINA_HOME environment variable should be set to the location of the
root directory of the "binary" distribution of Tomcat.
```

So I know I can do

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
```

But that will be gone next time I reboot the machine.

Should I put these in the root accounts .bashrc or .bash_profile or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I am using *setenv.sh* bash script, which is located in $TOMCAT_HOME/bin directory. *catalina.sh* script is referring to it by default.

Forgot to mention, that this script is not there by default. You need to create it and give *tomcat* user (or whatever user you use to run tomcat) to be able to execute it.

Comment: The docs say: "Apart from CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE, all environment variables can be specified in the "setenv" script". That would imply that there is somewhere else to put these to me.

Comment: You are right. I've checked my init script (/etc/init.d/tomcat , made on my own) and I am setting up CATALINA_HOME at the beginning of it.

Comment: The docs are kind of confusing. It says in another place that the recommended place to set these is a setenv script.